# what is [(selection)] in Angular 8?

Tags: angular8, two-way-binding

- Is it the same as [(ngModel)] ? Some kind of two-way binding ?
- I do have the following  tag on our project :

  ```
           <p-table #tt [value]="universitiesList"[(selection)]="selectedUniversity" [globalFilterFields]="['Name']">
  ```
- universitiesList and selectedUniversity are 2 variables which exist on the typescript of this component. I understand that. But are 'value' and 'selection' reserved words ? Why is value writen with [] and selection written within [()] ?

Ty a lot

Comment: Its all explained here: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/selection

Answer (score 1):

- **[(selection)]** is a property of a **primeNG table**
- It is a form of **two-way-binding**
- When a row / checkbox of the table is selected, the value is saved to that **array**
  (the value is saved to the array"selectedUniversity") :

  ```
              [(selection)]="selectedUniversity"
  ```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.9-lts/#/table/selection :

<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedCar1" dataKey="vin">